# Access VBA recordset Update runs fine but not updating

Tags: vba, recordset

I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. Mind you, the code was working fine all along until last week. We haven't made any changes to the code... so this is a mystery.

I have an Access VBA to update a record by incrementing by 1 by using recordset.update. 
The code looks something like this...

```
Sub UpdateQuarter(PersonName As String)
Dim dB As Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Quarter As Integer

Set dB = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("table")

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    rst.Edit
    If Name = rst!NameofPerson Then
        Quarter = rst!CurrentQuarter
        Quarter = Quarter + 1
        rst!CurrentQuarter = Quarter
        rst.Update
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have other Access database with very similar code (exact same structure) running perfectly fine. This code ALSO runs perfectly fine, and when I debug line by line, it shows that the correct values are being captured and incremented. However, it doesn't update the table!!

This is driving me crazy. Anyone have insight as to why this may occur??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would focus on finding out if it is truly a 'failure to update' issue, or a 'failure to find a match' issue. How about adding a couple of counters, then count how many names match and how many don't.  That may be helpful. Also, assume 'CurrentQuarter' is a numeric field? Oh, and DON'T use 'name' use 'strName'!!

Comment: I have ensured that it did find the correct match (the code above is sanitized. I have tested for a specific item and tested line by line). I have made sure that all variables and records such as rst!CurrentQuarter was updated to the new value when I hover my mouse over it in debug mode... but it doesn't update in the table. I didn't use 'name' haha again, it is sanitized :) but I'm sorry that may have confused you..

Comment: the bad thing about sanitized code is it is misleading. Take a look at where you say RSA!Edit ... now I don't know if that's a typo or it really does say RSA  instead of RST. do you have option explicit?

Comment: Oops. You are right. I changed that to RST. Only the variable names were sanitized, but I totally get your point. I had this code checked out by our IT team (dedicated coders) and they also don't see why this isn't working. It's as if the recent Microsoft Update messed this up, because it was working as of last week (and we didn't change a single thing in the code!)

Comment: Without knowing what the REAL code looks like, it is difficult to try and guess where the problem may be. BTW, you still have an issue because now you have changed your input parameter from 'name' to 'PersonName', yet didn't change all places. Is 'table' native? Or linked? Or SQL Server? Does your 'table' contain multiple matches? Have you tried using SQL (i.e. UPDATE table set xxx = 'yyy' where [name] = 'abcd')

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. I had this function as a call from another function, which worked on a same record set. I think this was causing the issue! I took out that call function and embedded the code into it directly and it works now!! Thanks for your suggestions and I'll try to be as precise as possible going forward.

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint in the middle of the loop, use F8 and check your variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually open your database and Ctrl+S and close it.
The SQL qwery will work after that.

And then won't work again.
Repeat step one...